# Python ctypes: get variable type and value problem

Tags: python, struct, union, ctypes

I want to use a C library in some Python code by using ctypes.
My problem is that I don't know C. I've been trying to read the code and about C structure for some days now, but I am stuck at one problem. I'm also fairly new to Python, since I'm currently making the switch from Matlab, and my Python is thus limited to scientific Python applications. This question is very specific, but I think the solution is of a general C library / Python link interest.

I'm using a library called Iphreeqc, a geochemical model, from `http://wwwbrr.cr.usgs.gov/projects/GWC_coupled/phreeqc/index.html´ (iphreeqc-2.18.0-5314.tar.gz , compiled from source on OS X 10.6. hyperlink not working due to SO spam prevention). I want to extract values from an evaluation made by the C library, into Python.

**I'm suspecting I'm making an error in the structures and union part of my Python code**, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Python code:

```
import ctypes

iphreeqc = ctypes.CDLL("libiphreeqc.0.dylib", ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)

# C structures from var.h 
class VAR_TYPE(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("TT_EMPTY",ctypes.c_int),
        ("TT_ERROR",ctypes.c_int),
        ("TT_LONG",ctypes.c_int),
        ("TT_DOUBLE",ctypes.c_int),
        ("TT_STRING",ctypes.c_int)]


(TT_EMPTY,
TT_ERROR,
TT_LONG,
TT_DOUBLE,
TT_STRING)=map(ctypes.c_int, xrange(5))


class VRESULT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("VR_OK",ctypes.c_int),
        ("VR_OUTOFMEMORY",ctypes.c_int),
        ("VR_BADVARTYPE",ctypes.c_int),
        ("VR_INVALIDARG",ctypes.c_int),
        ("VR_INVALIDROW",ctypes.c_int),
        ("VR_INVALIDCOL",ctypes.c_int)]

(VR_OK,
 VR_OUTOFMEMORY,
 VR_BADVARTYPE,
 VR_INVALIDARG,
 VR_INVALIDROW,
 VR_INVALIDCOL)=map(ctypes.c_int, xrange(0,-6,-1))

class _U(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = [("lVal", ctypes.c_long),
                ("dVal", ctypes.c_double),
                ("sVal", ctypes.c_char),
                ("vresult", VRESULT)]

class VAR(ctypes.Structure):
   _anonymous_ = ("pvar",)
   _fields_ = [
        ("pvar", _U),
        ("type", VAR_TYPE)]

# Run model        
Id=iphreeqc.CreateIPhreeqc()
dbloade = iphreeqc.LoadDatabase(Id,"phreeqc.dat")
estring=iphreeqc.OutputErrorString(Id)

# Model input
iphreeqc.AccumulateLine(Id,"TITLE Example 2.--Temperature dependence of solubility")
iphreeqc.AccumulateLine(Id,"                  of gypsum and anhydrite             ")
iphreeqc.AccumulateLine(Id,"SOLUTION 1 Pure water                                 ")
iphreeqc.AccumulateLine(Id,"        pH      7.0                                   ")
iphreeqc.AccumulateLine(Id,"        temp    25.0                                  ")
iphreeqc.AccumulateLine(Id,"EQUILIBRIUM_PHASES 1                                  ")
iphreeqc.AccumulateLine(Id,"        Gypsum          0.0     1.0                   ")
iphreeqc.AccumulateLine(Id,"        Anhydrite       0.0     1.0                   ")
iphreeqc.AccumulateLine(Id,"REACTION_TEMPERATURE 1                                ")
iphreeqc.AccumulateLine(Id,"        25.0 75.0 in 50 steps                         ")
iphreeqc.AccumulateLine(Id,"SELECTED_OUTPUT                                       ")
iphreeqc.AccumulateLine(Id,"        -file   ex2.sel                               ")
iphreeqc.AccumulateLine(Id,"        -user_punch true                                  ")
iphreeqc.AccumulateLine(Id,"        -reset false                                  ")
iphreeqc.AccumulateLine(Id,"        -simulation false                                  ")
iphreeqc.AccumulateLine(Id,"        -selected_out true                                  ")
iphreeqc.AccumulateLine(Id,"        USER_PUNCH                                      ")
iphreeqc.AccumulateLine(Id,"        -start                                           ")
iphreeqc.AccumulateLine(Id,"        10 punch - LA('H+')                                  ")
iphreeqc.AccumulateLine(Id,"        -end                                            ")
iphreeqc.AccumulateLine(Id,"END                                                       ")

# run model
runout=iphreeqc.RunAccumulated(Id)
estring2=iphreeqc.OutputErrorString(Id)

a=iphreeqc.GetSelectedOutputRowCount(Id)
b=iphreeqc.GetSelectedOutputColumnCount(Id)
print a
print b # this works, gives correct number of rows and columns  

vart=VAR() 
iphreeqc.VarInit(ctypes.byref(vart)) 

c=iphreeqc.GetSelectedOutputValue(Id, 43, 0, ctypes.byref(vart)) #tries to extract value from row 43, column 1

print c # c is here VRESULT. this works properly giving the right error number (0 to -6). Gives 0 in this case which is VR_OK
```

The value in the selected row,column is a double, but I've also tried with string values and long (integer) values at no success.
I expect vart.dVal (or .sVal or lVal in case of string or long) to contain the value I want, but it does not.
I would also expect one of the TT_ fields from VAR_TYPE to be 1, but they are all 0.
It seems that the .dVal,.sVal and .lVal actually contains the VAR_TYPE number (between 0 and 4), and reports this correctly (i.e. 3 for type double, 2 for long).

**My question is: how can I fix the code to make the VAR_TYPE fields reflect the variable type, which is now returned in .lVal field.
And how can I get the value I want to extract to the correct vart.xVal field? Am I lacking some pointers in the Python structure/union code?**

The C source where the structures and union is from (Var.h):

http://wwwbrr.cr.usgs.gov/projects/GWC_coupled/iphreeqc/Var_8h_source.html

A C example of what I'm trying to reproduce in Python (v is the variable 'vart' in my Python code, I'm ignoring the loops etc for now):

```
VAR v;
VarInit(&v);

  printf("selected-output:\n");
  for (i = 0; i < GetSelectedOutputRowCount(id); ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < GetSelectedOutputColumnCount(id); ++j) {
      if (GetSelectedOutputValue(id, i, j, &v) == VR_OK) {
        switch (v.type) {
        case TT_LONG:
          printf("%ld ", v.lVal);
          break;
        case TT_DOUBLE:
          printf("%g ", v.dVal);
          break;
        case TT_STRING:
          printf("%s ", v.sVal);
          break;
        }
      }
      VarClear(&v);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
```

The C example is taken from: (scroll a bit down)
http://wwwbrr.cr.usgs.gov/projects/GWC_coupled/iphreeqc/IPhreeqc_8h.html#a9f0ffd11e25a7e8f05d800623b14acf5

I'm using ctypes 1.1.0, Python 2.6.6 on OS X 10.6.6

Sorry for the length of this question, and hope some smart minds can help me out, or point me in the right direction.

Thanks a lot

Comment: If that's really your indentation, you're assigning to `TT_EMPTY`, etc. outside of the class. Might also want to look into [ctypesgen](http://code.google.com/p/ctypesgen/). EDIT: And `sVal` should be ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)

Comment: That was indeed my indentation, thanks for the heads up and for the ctypesgen tip. The answer posted below by Mark Tolonen worked out, also without the POINTER, but I will experiment some more with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue is enums are not structures.  Also make sure the fields in your structure are in the same order as the C header ('type' comes first).  Try this:

```
import ctypes

VAR_TYPE = ctypes.c_int
TT_EMPTY  = 0
TT_ERROR  = 1
TT_LONG   = 2
TT_DOUBLE = 3
TT_STRING = 4

VRESULT = ctypes.c_int
VR_OK          =  0
VR_OUTOFMEMORY = -1
VR_BADVARTYPE  = -2
VR_INVALIDARG  = -3
VR_INVALIDROW  = -4
VR_INVALIDCOL  = -5

class _U(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = [
        ('lVal',ctypes.c_long),
        ('dVal',ctypes.c_double),
        ('sVal',ctypes.c_char_p),
        ('vresult',VRESULT)]

class VAR(ctypes.Structure):
    _anonymous_ = ('u',)
    _fields_ = [
        ('type',VAR_TYPE),
        ('u',_U)]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly for all data types! I was doubting how to deal with the enums, but now I know better, also regarding the order of the fields.

Answer (score 1):

There is PhreeqPy (http://www.phreeqpy.com) that should work for your problem.
Disclaimer: I am the author.

PhreeqPy is a wrapper around the IPhreeqc COM/DLL/shared library.
You should get the COM functionality via the shared library on Linux or
Mac OS.

Here is part of the part of the code that handles the union and the structure:

```
class VARUNION(ctypes.Union):
    # pylint: disable-msg=R0903
    # no methods
    """Union with types.

    See Var.h in PHREEQC source.
    """
    c_int = ctypes.c_int
    _fields_ = [('long_value', ctypes.c_long),
                ('double_value', ctypes.c_double),
                ('string_value', ctypes.c_char_p),
                ('error_code', c_int)]

class VAR(ctypes.Structure):
    # pylint: disable-msg=R0903
    # no methods
    """Struct with data type and data values.

    See Var.h in PHREEQC source.
    """
    c_int = ctypes.c_int
    _fields_ = [('type', c_int),
                ('value', VARUNION)]
```